# Trouble writing data to database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote the following script.  My intention was to do the two following things:

1. Let a user see the current value of `$score`.
2. Let the user increment the `$score` by 1 by pressing the "Score!" button.

The value of `$score` is stored in a database.

Only one problem -- when I click the "Score!" button, the value of `$score` doesn't get incremented by one -- it gets reset to zero, regardless of what the original value is.

```
<?php
    $page_title = "";
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title><?php print($page_title) ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php // Script number 1.2, filename show_score.php

    // error handling
    ini_set('display errors',1);  // Let me learn from my mistakes!
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); // Show all possible problems! 

    // Set page title. 
    $page_title = "Game Score";

    // Connect to the database:
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
    mysql_select_db('game_scores',$link);

    // Create database query that gets the value of the score_counter cell
    $sql = 'SELECT score_counter FROM scores';
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);

    // Create a variable, $score_counter, that holds the array that 
    //is the result of the previous SQL query

    $score_counter = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // You don't really want the whole array, just score_counter[0],
    // so assign score_counter[0] its own variable, $score

    $scores = $score_counter[0];

    // Now that you've retrieved the current number of scores from the 
    // database, and extracted that number from an array and 
    // put it in its own variable, print it out on the screen.

    echo 'The current number of scores is ' . $scores . ' scores.';


    // Now let users add to the number of scores by clicking the "score" button. 

    if(isset($_POST['score'])){

        // increment the number of scores:
        $scores++;

        // create the SQL query:
        $query='UPDATE scores SET score_counter="$scores" WHERE score_id=1';

        // run the SQL query:
        mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");
        }

    ?>

    <H1>Score Counter</H1>

    <p>Click to add one point.</p>

    <form action ="show_score.php" method ="post">
    <input type ="submit" name ="score" value="score">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions, as they are being deprecated. Instead, use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Why not `update scores set score_counter=score_counter+1`, for this trivial example?

Comment: You're using double-quotes in SQL, which is frowned upon. Change them to single-quotes. If it's a numeric value, they're not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  I just wrote an include file to connect to the database using mysqli.

Comment: Good suggestion, MarcB.  I'm such a noob that my code is the programming equivalent of Bambi walking on the frozen pond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your query is in single quotes which makes your variable `$scores` become the literal word $scores. As a result your number data type (prob int) is converting it to a zero.

Change your query to this:

```
$query='UPDATE scores SET score_counter="'.$scores.'" WHERE score_id=1';
```

I used concatenation to make sure the value of `$scores` was used in the query instead of of the literal word $scores.

Comment: Agreed... also you appear to be showing the score before you increment the value so... i would probably move that echo line to after the block with the $score++

Comment: @SublymeRick  You're right -- the current code (with the changes suggested by John that make it actually work) doesn't show the new score unless you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

To use variable interpolation in PHP strings, you need to use double quotes:

```
$query="UPDATE scores SET score_counter=$scores WHERE score_id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$query='UPDATE scores SET score_counter="$scores" WHERE score_id=1';
```

with

```
$query='UPDATE scores SET score_counter="' .$scores. '" WHERE score_id=1';
```

it is taking $score as word, which doesn't exist in DB

Comment: i think you have your answer backwards